# How to use logging to reduce verification variability

Tags: dafny, formal-verification

I have a project with great variabilities in verification times. I can now call the Dafny logger (see below), but I don't know

- How to use the text or csv format to improve the verification.
- Should I instead use *.trx format and then use the tool to process
  that?
- What use (if any) is vcsSplitOnEveryAssert?

p.s. How to call the Dafny logger:

```
dafny verify seq_of_sets_example7.dfy --verification-time-limit:45 --cores:20 --log-format text --boogie -randomSeedIterations:10 --boogie -vcsSplitOnEveryAssert | tee TestResults\del3.txt
```

Someone else might want a different # of cores, a different format (e.g. csv and no "tee"), not to use Split, etc.

p.p.s. Here is a subset of my code that shows the issue: https://github.com/CarlKCarlK/dafnyrepro_sept23

Comment: I have not had any real success with `vcsSplitOnEveryAssert`

Comment: Follow up: With Divyanshu Ranjan's help, we got everything to verify reliably. We wrote up our experience in https://towardsdatascience.com/nine-rules-to-formally-validate-rust-algorithms-with-dafny-part-1-5cb8c8a0bb92

Answer (score 4):

We are using the logging feature to check for variability as you are describing.  We have set it up in the CI pipeline (see [here](https://github.com/Consensys/evm-dafny/actions/runs/6093162355/job/16532370780) and open "Verification Logs").  A key approach was to [parse and process the CSV file](https://github.com/Consensys/evm-dafny/blob/master/src/main/java/dafnyevm/util/DafnyLogSummariser.java) to provide more useful information in the analysis phase.

**Analysis**

What we generate from the csv file looks like this:

```
Name                                                        Resource Usage (CoV)
================================================================================
[5][WF] Precompiled.CallModExp                                     17.46M (0.00)
[5][CO] Int.LemmaToFromBytes                                       7.018M (0.21)
[5][CO] Gas.QuadraticCostIsMonotonic                               2.672M (0.51)
[5][WF] ExecutingState                                             1.655M (0.01)
[5][WF] EVM.ExecuteBytecode                                        1.581M (0.00)
...
```

We see Dafny functions with their mean resource usage and [Coefficient of Variation (CoV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) on the right hand side.  The CoV tells us how much variability there is.  The higher the number, the more variability.  The results are sorted by mean resource usage.  This is important for focus.  For example, functions with high variability but low average resource usage are not really problematic.

**Resolution**

Now, the hard part.  Having identified some functions with high variability, the next question is what to do.  There are not really any clear rules here (see [here](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/wiki/Investigating-slow-verification-performance) for some guidelines).    Some rules of thumb:

1. **Bit vectors** (e.g. `bv32`) have proven highly problematic.  Reducing and eliminating (where possible) use of these types significantly reduced variability for us.
2. **Non-Linear Arithmetic** has also proven highly problematic.  Eliminating this is often difficult because its doing something specific.  Using intermediate assertions can help.  Applying the `--disable-nonlinear-arithmetic` option along with [lemmas from the standard library](https://github.com/dafny-lang/libraries/tree/master/src/NonlinearArithmetic) is another strategy.
3. **Quantifiers** are also a known problem, and using triggers can help here substantially in some cases.

For example, looking at the analysis above, we see `Gas.QuadraticCostIsMonotonic` is perhaps one target for improvement.  This uses non-linear arithmetic which is the source of its problems.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at code, I would guess that quantifier initialization is major source of problem why verification is timing out. I am particularly suspicious about `ValidSeq` and few of preconditions which are `forall`, which might be doing lots of initialization. One way to make proof more stable is to hide body of predicate and preconditions and reveal only at location where it is needed like shown below

```
ghost predicate {:opaque} ValidSeq(sequence: seq<int>) {
  (forall i :nat, j:nat | i < j < |sequence| :: sequence[i] < sequence[j])
}
    
lemma TestLemmaV1(xs: seq<int>)
  requires ValidSeq(xs)
  requires |xs| >= 2
  ensures xs[0] < xs[1]
{
  assert xs[0] < xs[1] by {
    reveal ValidSeq();
  }
}

lemma TestLemmaV2(xs: seq<int>)
  requires A: forall i, j :: 0 <= i < j < |xs| ==> xs[i] < xs[j]
  requires |xs| >= 2
  ensures xs[0] < xs[1]
{
  assert xs[0] < xs[1] by {
    reveal A;
  }
}
```